# Should weights on earlier layers change less than weights on later layers in a neural network

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent

I'm trying to debug why my neural network isn't working. One of the things I've observed is that the weights between the input layer and the first hidden layer hardly change at all, whereas weights later in the network (eg. the weights between the last hidden layer and the output) change significantly. Is this to be expected or a symptom of an error in my code?

I'm applying backpropagation and gradient descent to alter the weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected and well established - **Vanished Gradient**

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem
>
> This has the effect of multiplying n of these small numbers to compute gradients of the "front" layers in an n-layer network, meaning that the gradient (error signal) decreases exponentially with n and the front layers train very slowly.

While I'm not an expert in neural network (experts, please add an answer), I'm sure professional implementation for neural network is tricky and **highly optimized**. If you simply implement a vanilla text-book-styled neural network, you won't be able to use it to train a large network. Keep it small and you'll be fine.

Comment: I would add that there are 2 things the OP could do: 1) Check their implementation is correctly calculating gradients by implementing gradient testing. 2) Implement and try ReLU activation function, which suffers less from vanishing gradient problems (provided there are enough positive activations).